# In reStructuredText, how to control indentation of 'parsed-literal'?

Tags: indentation, restructuredtext

If I write this reStructuredText:

```
Blah, blah.

    Here is my code:

.. parsed-literal::

    some code
```

and then convert it to HTML with `rst2html`, `some code` is rendered as less indented than "Here is my code:".

How can I get `some code` indented by as much as "Here is my code:"? In other words, how can I vertically align `some code` and "Here is my code:"?

Comment: Please don't include irrelevant tags (e.g. [tag:markdown] in this case).

Answer (score 0):

Your example is rendered into this piece of html code:

```
<p>Blah, blah.</p>
<blockquote>
Here is my code:</blockquote>
<pre class="literal-block">
some code
</pre>
```

Which doesn't make much sense: line `Here is my code:` is not a quote here.

So I would rather write it this way:

```
Blah, blah.

Here is my code:

.. parsed-literal::

    some code
```

which renders to:

```
<p>Blah, blah.</p>
<p>Here is my code:</p>
<pre class="literal-block">
some code
</pre>
```

Then to change an alignment of `some code` block, you would need to tweak css.

Comment: I do want both `Here is my code:` and `some code` to be indented, and I do want them to be indented by the same amount.